# Save tracking data from Leap Motion with p5.js to .csv

Tags: javascript, csv, p5.js, leap-motion

I need to write a script in p5.js to track the position of the five fingertips (on one or both hands) at a set interval (e.g. 20 ms), and then save the time-finger data to a .csv

I have previously done this in Processing with Table and getting the PVector for the fingers, but I have no idea on how to do this with javascript.

Any and all input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. For example, are you asking how to connect a Leap Motion to a P5.js sketch? Or are you asking how to output a `.csv` file from a P5.js sketch? Those two things are completely independent of each other, and that's how you should approach them.

Try to get a simple "hello world" sketch running. Now add very basic Leap Motion functionality: print something to the screen or the console. Separately from that, try to save a `.csv` file that contains some hard-coded values. Then maybe do something like save the previous 100 mouse positions to a `.csv` file.

Work your way forward in small steps like that, and if you get stuck, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the clarification concering Stackoverflow!